# Is convergence in $I^I$ topology equivalent to point-wise convergence?

Tags: general-topology

The $I^I$ topology is the uncountable Cartesian product (Tychonoff) of the closed unit interval $[0,1]$. We can imagine it as a space of all the functions from $[0,1]$ to itself.

I was told that a sequence $\alpha_n$ converges to $\alpha$ in this space if and only if the function $\alpha_n(x)$ converges to $\alpha(x)$ point-wisely. But I'm a little bit skeptical about that.

For example, let 
$$\alpha_n(x)=\frac{x(1-x)^n}{\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n},$$
the famous point-wisely but not uniformly convergent function sequence that converges to $\alpha(x)=0$.

Now, look at the open set of all the functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,0.5)$, it is clearly an open neighborhood of $\alpha(x)=0$, but it is disjoint from the sequence of $\alpha_n$, which means that the sequence is not convergent. Am I right about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: the set of all functions from $[0,1]$ to $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ is not open in the topology of pointwise convergence or the product topology (which is the same thing). Every open nbhd of a function in that set includes functions that take the value $0$ somewhere.

Comment: According to Tychonoff, the set $F_\xi$ of all the functions that satisfies $\alpha(\xi)\in[0,0.5)$ for some particular $\xi\in[0,1]$ is open, because it is the pre-image of $[0,0.5)$ in the $\xi$-coordinate projection from $I^I$ to $I$. And the set $F$ of all the functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,0.5)$ is the intersection of all the $F_\xi$, $\xi\in[0,1]$, so $F$ must be open also. Right?

Comment: @Voldemort: No: intersections of **finitely** many open sets are guaranteed to be open, but not intersections of infinitely many open sets. If arbitrary intersections of open sets were open, $\Bbb R$ would have the discrete topology, because for any $x\in\Bbb R$ we have $$\{x\}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n\right)\;.$$

Comment: Aww, that's where I went wrong. So can you describe a typical open set in $I^I$? Can we slightly modify the set $F$ to make it open?

Comment: @Voldemort: It’s very difficult, if not impossible, to describe a general open set in $I^I$ in an intuitively satisfying way. In general you’re best off looking at basic open sets: choose a finite set of indices $\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$, for each of these indices $i_k$ an open subset $U_k$ of $I$, and look at $$\left\{f\in I^I:f(i_k)\in U_k\text{ for }k=1,\dots,n\right\}\;.$$ The answer to the second question is *no*: it’s just way too far from being open in that topology.

Comment: Aww, right. And since Tychonoff specified that the topology has to be the *coarsest*, we have that an open neighborhood of any function in $I^I$ can only limit the function values at finite positions in $[0,1]$, right?

Comment: @Voldemort: Yes, that’s right. When you get right down to it, it’s a pretty coarse topology when there are infinitely many factors. To get the sort of behavior that I think you have in mind, you want the uniform topology (if you think of it as a function space) or the [box topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) (if you think of it as a product of topological spaces).

Comment: Now I see. Thank you very much for explaining so patiently.

Comment: @Voldemort: You’re welcome; glad to help.